# page object model split object and action in selenium

Tags: selenium, pageobjects

I am working in selenium based automation framework.
I have Dashboard page. Dashboard page have 100 and above web elements.
It also contains corresponding actions. 
Can I split the web elements in one class file and action in one class file?

Answer (score 3):

The methods in the `Page Object` depends on the `WebElements` (in case of using `PageFactory`) or the locators for those elements. Separating the `WebElements` and the methods will break the `Page Object` design pattern and object-oriented class structure in general.

You can find more details and examples in [seleniumhq](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/06_test_design_considerations.jsp#page-object-design-pattern) and [github](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/PageFactory) docs.